# TinyMCE4 equivalent of toolbar location external?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-3

In TinyMCE 3 you can use [`theme_advanced_toolbar_location = 'external'`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x%3atheme_advanced_toolbar_location) in mce settings, making a class=mceExternalToolbar element.

However, there doesn't seem to be an exact equivalent for TinyMCE 4. Am I missing something, or is an external toolbar that sticks to top when scrolling down, not easily doable in TinyMCE 4?

Answer (score 7):

In TinyMCE 3, "theme_advanced_toolbar_location" is a theme option of the "advanced" theme, which is one of the official themes(the other is simple, you can see these 2 themes in folder tiny_mce\themes)

But in TinyMCE 4, there's no "advanced" theme, but a "modern" theme  as the default one, with this theme, there's an "inline" option, which is the equivalent of the old "external".

```
tinymce.init({
            //this will make the toolbar "external"
            inline : true,
            //.....
        });
```

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Inline

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/inline.php

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't add an element with class mceExternalToolbar, I assume any styling and behavior based on that would require complete rewrite? It looks like I also have something failing silently with this option, making only the textarea visible, no iframes created.

Comment: You're right, @NoBugs. Big changes with themes. There'a a "mce-tinymce-inline" class with "inline" mode, which might be helpful. Also, no iframe will be created, it uses div[contenteditable="true"] as the wysiwyg editor.

Comment: It's worth noting that the main difference of inline-mode is it uses a Contenteditable instead of an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.  Yes, there is a simple solution but it just didn't seem to come up in any search I did.  Eventually found it by accident when looking through the configuration options.

```
tinymce.init({
    inline: true,
    fixed_toolbar_container: "#mytoolbar"
});
```

[www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:fixed_toolbar_container](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:fixed_toolbar_container)

Answer (score 1):

Both answers helped me get a toolbar on the bottom, but this css will help keep it visible all the time.

```
/* make sure toolbar doesn't get hidden */

#toolbar > .mce-tinymce {
  display: block !important;
}
```

**CSS ONLY SOLUTION**

If you can use flexbox and only need to swap position you can use the following with respective prefixes to get the toolbar on the bottom:

```
.mce-tinymce > .mce-container-body {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's valid css?

Comment: @NoBugs my bad, converted from scss to css :)